# Subscribe and Unsubscribe not working in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I noticed that every time I push a page in stack it calls `ionViewloaded` and I add `subscribe()` my problem is I cannot unsubscribe, when I pop the page. Here is my code. It doesn't work.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.user = this.navParams.data;
    this.events.subscribe('close:userPopOver', this.onRemovePopOver.bind(this));
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    alert('FIRES!!');
    this.events.unsubscribe('close:userPopOver', this.onRemovePopOver.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both answers cannot be implemented for typescript did not recognize value of void passing to subscription instance, to make it work 
`this.events.unsubscribe('close:userPopOver',null)`

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/events-pub-sub-how-to-unsubscribe-in-lifecycle-hook/50596/5

Answer (score 0):

```
private sub : Subscription;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.user = this.navParams.data;
    this.sub = this.events.subscribe('close:userPopOver', this.onRemovePopOver.bind(this) );
 }

ionViewWillLeave(){
    alert('FIRES!!');
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Comment: does subscription is from rxjs/Rx?
i'm getting a warning type void not assignable to type 'Subscription'

Comment: `import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";`

Comment: this.events.subscribe() return void not able to assign to subscription

Comment: So you are subscribing to `void`? No this is wrong. It should be returning `Observable<T>`, or else you can not subscribe to it.

Comment: events.subscribe returns void

Comment: @domzgarcia Ok There were no details in your question regrading the event that was subscribed. In general I posted my answer so as to how unsubscribe() is usually done. Anyways you got it!. You can accept your own answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.